# Idiom for resuming an async system call in Fortran 2008

Tags: fortran, fortran2008

If I make a system call, eg:

```
  call execute_command_line (slowcall1, wait=.false., exitstat=i)
  call execute_command_line (slowcall2, wait=.false., exitstat=j)
  call execute_command_line (slowcall3, wait=.false., exitstat=k)
  call execute_command_line (slowcall4, wait=.false., exitstat=l)
```

I want to call these in parallel then to check on them as they progress, whether they have completed, and finally take some action.  However, polling exitstat doesn't give me that information.  What's the right idiom for checking whether my system call I am not waiting for has actually completed?

From here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html

It does not appear any of the optional arguments:

- EXITSTAT
- CMDSTAT
- CMDMSG

provide this information.

Is there a recommended modern Fortran procedure used involving writing lock files as part of the call?  Or a different asynchronous call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. The command as you are using it is "fire and forget". If you want any finer control, use threads. Not for parallelism, but for concurency.

Comment: Is this really true?  Looking back on this, from the documentations, it sure looks like the async is aimed at giving you the same kind of proc information you'd get with the OS system call.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I do not get what "same kind of information" you exactly mean.